# checkbox click event crashing

Tags: excel, checkbox

I'm working in Excel 2010. Having a problem with the Checkbox Control (ActiveX Control) crashing when I use a different Checkbox control name than conventionally assigned. Trying to code actions based on checked or not checked.

Does the naming protocol for Checkboxes require using the "Checkbox#" convention in order to support finding it when coding. Please don't laugh I'm not very technical, so what seems obvious to most is a major blind spot for me. Thank you for your help. I'm not excited about having Checkbox 1 through 100, when a more user friendly name would help my feeble brain.

Here is an example of the exact code under two different control names. The "Checkbox1" works the "CheckboxX" does not.

---

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If Checkbox1.Value = True Then

    Range("P9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("O9").Select

Else

    Range("O9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("O9").Select

End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CheckboxX_Click()

If Checkbox1.Value = True Then
    Range("P9").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("O9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("O9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("O9").Select

Else

    Range("O9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("O9").Select

End If

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Apparently, I'm blind as well as feeble. I just noticed my mistake. The "If statement" reference in the CheckboxX example doesn't match the control name.

Comment: If this question is now answered, you should either post an answer to your own question and mark it correct or delete the question. This is better for other people who stumble upon this post.